# Heavy load website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have an aspx website with many pages which accept user input, pull data from a SQL database, do some heavy data processing then finally present the data to the user.

The site is getting bigger and bigger and it is starting to put a lot of stress on the server.

What I want to do is to maybe separate things a bit:

Server-A will host the website, the site will accept input from users and pass those parameters to applications running on Server-B

Server-B will fetch data from SQL, do the heavy data processing, then pass a dataset or datatable object back to the website.

Is this possible?

Comment: [Maybe!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)

Comment: Sure it is possible. But are sure that the load is occurs on your web server? It seems like the load is actually on your database, unless they are running on the same machine.

Comment: If the same set of inputs will always result in the same output (and no update/delete/inserts are happening behind the scenes, a caching solution might be a good fit as well.

Comment: Oops closed by mistake. Voted to ReOpen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this is called an [N-Tier Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

The most obvious thing to separate is one database server, tuned to meet the demands of a database (fast disks, lots of RAM) and one or more separate web servers.

You can expand on that by placing an application tier between the web server and the database server.  The application tier can accept the user input that was collected in the web tier, interact with the database, do the heavy crunching, and return the result to the web tier.  Most typically, you would use [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (WCF) to expose the functionality of the application tier to the web server(s).  Application servers might often be tuned to have very fast CPU's and might have slower disks and possibly less memory than database servers, depending on exactly what they need to do.  The beauty of this solution is that you can just add more and more identical application servers as the load on your application grows.

Comment: Eric J. Why are you so much faster than me at answering questions ?! LOL... good job.

Comment: Well, the db server is separate from the web server. I was interested in knowing how to do the heavy data processing remotely.

Comment: @user1481183: Expanded my answer to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the business model, you need some caching strategy to prevent heavy calculation for each input.
Consider an stock website. Although there are many transactions each minute, they won't update market trend for each of them. They can schedule an update based on something like, defined intervals (hourly, daily...), defined number of interactions (based on count of value) etc.
The task should be done when the server load is low. This way visitors see the stock trend on main page while it is accurate enough.
For such heavy load scenarios, good design is everything since sometimes even the expensive hard-wares will not help much.
If you like, share some info about what is going done.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a load balancer like an F5

that way your architecture does not change and 
but i would use the ntier approach to split your site into a data and presentation layer 
then the load balancer will direct each request to the server with the lightest load

Comment: I would also note, datasets are great but costly. Don't use a dataset to get 1 value from 1 column.   Use datatables instead they are a bit lighter and always use the .dispose() method to free up the memory